# C3P0: unreturnedConnectionTimeout in production?

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0, persistence.xml

The parameter `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` times out unreturned connections after a given period of time. I'm trying to decide whether I should use this in my production `persistence.xml`? A big plus of using this is that the Connection Pool will be able to recover from leaky connections. A big minus is that leaky connections will be very difficult to detect.

Should I use `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` in production applications? If yes, what should its value be? Are there any other pros/cons I should consider?

Answer (score 7):

You should debug your Connection leaks, and then not use `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` in production, ideally.

To debug Connection leaks, set both `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`, see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients (archived [here](https://archive.fo/GCn5V)). Then, when you have no more leaks, unset both of these parameters.

You would set `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` in production mostly if for some reason you can't debug and fix the application whose Connections are leaking, in which case it's a reasonable workaround to just set `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and let c3p0 clean up what your application forgets to.